# How to show if the complex series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-i)^n}{\ln n}$ converges or diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I have the series
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-i)^n}{\ln n}$$
and I'm trying to determine whether the series will converge or diverge.The Ratio test gives me $L=1$, so it doesn't tell me anything.

I tried to use the comparison test, so I used $\ln n<n$ and thus $\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{\ln n}$ for all $n>2$. So I have:
$$|z_n|=\left|\frac{(-i)^n}{\ln n}\right|=\frac{1}{\ln n}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{n}<|z_n|$$ and since $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, thus $\sum_{n=2}^\infty |z_n|$ diverges, but I can't say that the series of $z_n$ diverges if the series of absolute values |$z_n|$ diverges. So, how can I show if this series converges or diverges?

Comment: You can use the Dirichlet test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s how I would argue:

The real terms and the imaginary terms of the series have nothing to do with each other. The real part is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{\log(2k)}$, while the imaginary part is $\bigl(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{\log(2k+3)}\bigr)i$.

More precisely, if $N\equiv1\pmod4$, that is, if $N=4K+1$, then
$$
\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{(-i)^n}{\log n}=\sum_{k=1}^{2K}\frac{(-1)^k}{\log(2k)}
\>+\>\biggl(\sum_{k=0}^{2K-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{\log(2k+3)}\biggr)i\>,
$$
in which I do hope that I have gotten the running indices right. At any rate, the real part and the imaginary part are, separately, alternating series, and there you are.

Comment: I see, you got the real and imaginary parts by analyzing what happens when $n$ is even and when $n$ is odd, right? Then you write the results as two new series with the index $k$. So, analyzing the real and imaginary series, by the alternating test, both real and imaginary series converge and thus the series as a whole converges, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, just so. There’s one step I left out, though: you have to check that when the upper limit on the finite sum is not $\equiv1\pmod4$, i.e. is of form $4K+2, 4K+3, 4K+4$, then the additional terms count for an amount that goes to zero with $K\to\infty$. This is easily done, and I think the heavy duty work is in the argument I gave above.